# QuickSort Algorithm implementation

Tags: algorithm, quicksort

I am not getting where i am going wrong implementing quicksort algorithm.
Below is the code:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int part(vector<int> &arr,int i,int j)
{

   int pivot=i;
    i++;


        while(i<j)
            {

            while(arr[i]<arr[pivot])
                i++;
            while(arr[j]>arr[pivot])
                j--;

            if(i<j)
                swap(arr[i],arr[j]);           


        }

        swap(arr[j],arr[pivot]);
        return j;


}


void quickSort(vector <int> &arr,int p,int r) {

    if(p<r)
        {


        int t=part(arr,p,r);


        quickSort(arr,p,t-1);  

        quickSort(arr,t+1,r);


    }




    }




int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;

    vector <int> arr(n);
    for(int i = 0; i < (int)n; ++i) {
        cin >> arr[i];
    }

    quickSort(arr,0,arr.size()-1);

    for(int i=0;i<arr.size();i++)
        cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    cout<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

i am giving input as 
7
5 8 1 3 7 9 2

but getting output as :
2 1 3 7 5 8 9

Can anyone please point out where i am going wrong.

Comment: What did you discover when you debugged the program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the "part" function you're swapping at the end, even if the values are already in place.
Just check the values before swapping:

```
int part(vector<int> &arr, int i, int j)
{
    int pivot = i;
    i++;
    while (i < j)
    {
        while (arr[i] < arr[pivot])
            i++;
        while (arr[j] > arr[pivot])
            j--;

        if (i < j)
            swap(arr[i], arr[j]);
    }
    if (arr[j] < arr[pivot]) {
        swap(arr[j], arr[pivot]);
    }
    return j;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not mistaken, the condition in

```
if(i<j)
    swap(arr[i],arr[j]);
```

in the function `part` is not correct; it should check the relation of the array values `arr[i]` and `arr[j]` instead of `i` and `j` to decide whether the array entries are to be swapped.